# ASP.NET client side validation on blur

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, rangevalidator

I have few textboxes and asp.net validation controls on a page. The validation fires when I click on "Submit" button. Is there anyway to fire the validation as soon as I leave the textbox? I would like to do the same validation for other 20+ fields in the form. However, only validating specific textbox when leaving it.

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtclass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvclass" 
           runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtclass" 
           ErrorMessage="Enter your class (6 - 12)" MaximumValue="12" 
           MinimumValue="6" Type="Integer">
        </asp:RangeValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a js function to perform the validating, then for each textbox you want to validate set the onblur and call that function. (I'm just free writing below so excuse the syntax error but you should get the gist)

```
  function validateClass(val)
  {
    if(val.value > 5 && val.value < 13)
      {
          //alert(good!)
      }
     else
     {
          //alert(show error?)
     }
  
  }
```

call it in your textbox

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtclass" runat="server" onblur="validateClass(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to use ASP.NET validation for this?

Comment: Onblur is a client-side event

Comment: Yes you can use ASP NET validation, you will probably want to use the RangeValidator (ensure value entered is in the range you specify) coupled with a Compare validator to ensure value is number.

Comment: The validation only fires when I click on submit button. How can I show the validation error as soon as a user leaves the textbox?

Comment: Do you have the onBlur wired to the correct textbox? OnBlur fires when the user leaves the object the onblur is set to. Can you show what code you have now?